# Find a limit of radicals

Tags: limits

How to find a limit where $x\to\infty$ of the following expression? What is the steps?

1. My first guess is to apply this rule to numerator: $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$

[image]

Comment: Your rule is not correct.  The plus sign on the right should be a minus sign.  Can you compare the size of the terms in the numerator as $x \to \infty$?  Similarly for the denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that won't help.  As $x \to \infty$, you simply look at the dominating powers within each sum.  For example, in the numerator, $x^2+1$ looks like $x^2$. Then $\sqrt{x^2+1} \sim \sqrt{x^2} = x$.  $x+\sqrt{x}$ then approximates $x$ in this limit, so the numerator behaves as $x$.

In the denominator, $x^3+x$ becomes $x^3$, so that $\sqrt[4]{x^3+x}$ approximates $x^{3/4}$. Then the denominator behaves as $-x$ because $x$ dominates $x^{3/4}$.

The limit is then $x/(-x) = -1$.

Answer (score 3):

We can assume $\;x>0\;$ (why?)

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt[4]{x^3+x}-x}\cdot\frac{\frac1x}{\frac1x}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}+\sqrt\frac1x}{\sqrt[4]{\frac1x+\frac1{x^3}}-1}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac1{-1}=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^3+x}-x}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(\sqrt{1+1/x^2}+1/\sqrt{x})}{x(\sqrt[4]{1/x+1/x^3}-1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}+1/\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[4]{1/x+1/x^3}-1}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+0}+0}{\sqrt[4]{0+0}-1}=-1
\end{aligned}
$$